# Confused about concentration & temperature vs voltage of a Daniell cell

Tags: electrochemistry, nernst-equation

I am doing a lab that looks at how the temperature of each half cell in a $\ce{ Zn_{(s)} / Zn^{2+}_{(aq)} || Cu^{2+}_{(aq)} / Cu_{(s)} }$ cell affects the potential difference across the Cu-Zn electrodes. I'm trying to look into the theory behind the experiment. (I know that a "proper" analysis requires deeper knowledge in kinetics and physical chem, but I can't use anything beyond the high school curriculum in my background information section, please understand)

Anyways, the Nernst equation suggests that

$$E_{\ce{Zn}} = E_{\ce{Zn}}^{Ø} - \frac{RT}{2F} \ln\left( \frac{1}{[\ce{Zn^{2+}}]} \right)$$

and

$$E_{\ce{Cu}} = E_{\ce{Cu}}^{Ø} - \frac{RT}{2F} \ln\left( \frac{1}{[\ce{Cu^{2+}}]} \right)$$

where $T$ is the temperature of the species's half cell.

Since $E_{\text{cell}}=E_{\ce{Cu}} -E_{\ce{Zn}}$, I can write

$$E_{\text{cell}} = \bigg( -\frac{R}{2F} \ln \left( \frac{1}{[\text{heated species}]} \right) \bigg) \cdot T + C$$.

The intercept $C$ of the slope with the ordinate will be the potential of the half-cell that isn't heated (assumed to be constant with constant temperature).

Now I'm confused whether this implies that $E_{\text{cell}}$ **increases** with higher temperature if the concentration of the heated species is greater than 1, the **opposite** for $[\text{heated species}] < 1$, and **no change** at all for $[\text{heated species}] = 1$. Just seems counter-intuitive. Any help is appreciated :D

Comment: Note that [standard redox potentials E° change with temperature](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/135423/does-standard-electrode-potential-depend-upon-temperature), as standard reaction Gibbs energy generally changes with temperature too.  The temperature in the Nernst equation describes rather potential change due activity change at the given temperature.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Note, *chemical* information may be advantageously formatted using on ChemSE with [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/). Take moment to familiarize with this. You are encouraged to use it in the body of questions, answers, and comments. Because it is something special not all web browsers understand well, *do not* use it in the title of questions or answers.